# How to keep text with prior div (eliminate newline)

Tags: css

I have a project in which I'm parsing some text and reformatting it with `div`s wrapped around key sections.  I'm using divs because I specifically need to outdent the first line of each section, for which I'm using `left-padding` along with negative `text-indent`.  Everything is working fine, except for one issue:  due to the nature of the text and the way I need to parse it, many sections will need to end with a comma which cannot be included in the prior div.  So I end up with a comma that floats on its own line.  I'd like to find a way to make the comma stay with the prior div instead of appearing on a new line.  **Note**: changing the parsing routine to move the comma inside the prior div will be complex; I'm specifically looking for a way to do this in CSS *without* moving the comma inside the prior div.

Here's a simplified example of the output of what my parse-to-html routine  produces ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc9do6te/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      .inner {
        padding-left: 8ch;
        text-indent: -6ch;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis leo diam. Donec mattis erat eget augue pellentesque sodales. Aliquam et augue eget libero mollis hendrerit eu a purus. Morbi bibendum, nunc eget lobortis porttitor, tortor velit posuere ex, at tempor eros orci auctor magna. Praesent maximus malesuada sodales. Integer convallis eget orci eget cursus</div>,
      <div class="inner">Mauris aliquam luctus sem, non cursus libero cursus non. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum dignissim nisi eu elit placerat, vel euismod quam elementum. Nam fringilla tristique nibh a mattis. Duis finibus lacus libero, quis efficitur sem egestas vitae. Nunc auctor enim lectus, non finibus est tincidunt ut. Nulla commodo odio ut nisl ullamcorper vehicula.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you view the rendered output, you'll see that between the two `inner` `div`s, there's a comma that appears on its own line.  I'd like it at the end of the final line of the previous div.  In order to get the outdenting, I need to use `div` instead of `span`.  Is there any way to make that comma appear at the end of the prior div, without moving it inside the div?

Also:  I'm targeting Electron.js, so I don't need an every-browser solution.  Something that works in latest Chrome is sufficient.

Edit to add:  if it helps, assume I can wrap additional tags around the content, including around the `div` + comma.  It's moving the comma that is expensive (for my value of expensive).

Comment: I can't think of any way to mitigate this in CSS. You could hypothetically write some JavaScript to move the commas to the previous `<div>`. Though, employing workarounds to avoid fixing the root cause seems like a smell to me.

Comment: I know you said you were looking for a CSS solution, but could this be accomplished with javascript? Something like `var fullPageSearch = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;` and `var foundComma = fullPageSearch.search(" , ");` I am scraping at air here, but I am wondering if you search the entire page for a string containing a comma with a space on either side of it, it would exclude all commas that are in "the right place" (ie directly adjacent to another character) and pick up the comma between the divs. You could then append an empty string to that character.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the cleanest solution, but since you can't put the comma in the div you will need to set the div to display as `inline` (or switch it to a `span`) so that the comma appears next to the text and handle the line break with wrapping the comma and adding a pseudo element. E.g.:

```
  .container {
    padding-left: 8ch;
  }

  .inner {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -6ch;
  }

  .comma:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
  }
```

See this update to your [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qraomd5x/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I have come with this solution for you if you don't want to change the `HTML` code at all!

CSS will add a comma after the `div.inner` while javaScript will remove the existing comma.

```js
      let comma = document.querySelectorAll('.inner');
      for (let i = 0; i < comma.length; i++){
        comma[i].nextSibling.textContent = '';
      }
```

```css
      .inner {
        padding-left: 8ch;
        text-indent: -6ch;
        margin-bottom:15px;/*adds extra space at bottom*/
      }
        .inner:after{
            content: ",";
        }
        .inner:last-child::after{
            content: "";
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis leo diam. Donec mattis erat eget augue pellentesque sodales. Aliquam et augue eget libero mollis hendrerit eu a purus. Morbi bibendum, nunc eget lobortis porttitor, tortor velit posuere ex, at tempor eros orci auctor magna. Praesent maximus malesuada sodales. Integer convallis eget orci eget cursus</div>,
      <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis leo diam. Donec mattis erat eget augue pellentesque sodales. Aliquam et augue eget libero mollis hendrerit eu a purus. Morbi bibendum, nunc eget lobortis porttitor, tortor velit posuere ex, at tempor eros orci auctor magna. Praesent maximus malesuada sodales. Integer convallis eget orci eget cursus</div>,
      <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis leo diam. Donec mattis erat eget augue pellentesque sodales. Aliquam et augue eget libero mollis hendrerit eu a purus. Morbi bibendum, nunc eget lobortis porttitor, tortor velit posuere ex, at tempor eros orci auctor magna. Praesent maximus malesuada sodales. Integer convallis eget orci eget cursus</div>,
      <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis leo diam. Donec mattis erat eget augue pellentesque sodales. Aliquam et augue eget libero mollis hendrerit eu a purus. Morbi bibendum, nunc eget lobortis porttitor, tortor velit posuere ex, at tempor eros orci auctor magna. Praesent maximus malesuada sodales. Integer convallis eget orci eget cursus</div>,
      <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis leo diam. Donec mattis erat eget augue pellentesque sodales. Aliquam et augue eget libero mollis hendrerit eu a purus. Morbi bibendum, nunc eget lobortis porttitor, tortor velit posuere ex, at tempor eros orci auctor magna. Praesent maximus malesuada sodales. Integer convallis eget orci eget cursus</div>,
      <div class="inner">Mauris aliquam luctus sem, non cursus libero cursus non. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum dignissim nisi eu elit placerat, vel euismod quam elementum. Nam fringilla tristique nibh a mattis. Duis finibus lacus libero, quis efficitur sem egestas vitae. Nunc auctor enim lectus, non finibus est tincidunt ut. Nulla commodo odio ut nisl ullamcorper vehicula.</div>
    </div>
```